# Issue wwith relative paths in DotNetNuke

Tags: asp.net, css, dotnetnuke, relative-path

I have created custom dnn module.
Module is a separate assembly of course.
In module project I have folder `Images`.
And I have terrible issue to reference images with relative paths.
I have tried

```
background: url(~/Images/image01.png)
background: url(~/MyCustomModule/Images/image01.png)
background: url(~/DesktopModules/MyCustomModule/Images/image01.png)
etc.
```

and nothing works.
Only way to make it to work is when I write something like:

```
background: url(../../DesktopModules/MyCustomModule/Images/image01.png)
```

but this works on my production server but not in my local dnn instalation.
Is there any proper way to reference images in this folder?

Answer (score 8):

Within your CSS file you have a few options.

Using a rooted path

```
background: url(/DesktopModules/MyModule/Images/MyImage.png);
```

this will work, but ONLY if not in a "child portal" or non-virtual directory setup.

The best option if you can do it is to make the URL's relative to the css file itself...

So, if your css is in /DesktopModules/MyModule you would then user

```
background: url(Images/MyImage.png);
```

This should work in both situations.

Answer (score 4):

Reason: Server name is missing. On the local machine, the address looks like `http://localhost/<servername>` - for example mine is `http://localhost/dnn6.`

The reason it doesn't work on the local machine is because the browser is looking for the images at `http://localhost/Images/image01.png or http://localhost/DesktopModules/MyCustomModule/Images/image01.png.`

I prefer to insert my css and other scripts on the code behind. That way the server name is included and it works on both production and development server.

```
LiteralControl litScripts = new LiteralControl();
litScripts.Text +="<link href=\"" + this.TemplateSourceDirectory + 
"/CSS/Form.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(litScripts);
```

On my production server, the url looks like

```
<link href="/DesktopModules/MyCustomModule/CSS/Form.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and on the development server, it is inserted as

```
<link href="/DNN6/DesktopModules/MyCustomModule/CSS/Form.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Now edit the Form.css to look like this,

```
background: url(../Images/image01.png)
```

Answer (score 1):

The links you use in your top example would not typically work in a CSS file. The `~` is something special handled by ASP.NET that indicates *The root of the application*. Your CSS file will have no clue what that is, and will pass it on literally, which likely will break the links.

Instead of using a relative path, could you use a rooted path, which starts with the slash? What ever is correct for where the files are:

```
background: url(/DesktopModules/MyCustomModule/Images/image01.png)
background: url(/MyApplication/DesktopModules/MyCustomModule/Images/image01.png)
background: url(/MyApp/Subdir/DesktopModules/MyCustomModule/Images/image01.png)
```

Just be sure the URL starts with a leading `/` to signify "the root of the website"

Comment: When I type 'background: url(/DesktopModules/MyCustomModule/Images/image01.png)' it works on production but not on local dnn :(

Answer (score 0):

css files doesn't know any thing about ~ character.  The path should be relative to the location of those css files